# C# hacer POST con archivo a Web API usando CURL

Tags: c#, curl

Tengo que armar la siguiente solicitud en C# (muestro el ejemplo en Postman que funciona correctamente):

[image: Solicitud desde Postman]

Logre armarla usando HttpClient y ForUrlEncodedContent, pero no se como incluir el archivo en la solicitud:

[image: Solicitud desde C#, sin el archivo]

Donde parametros seria lo siguiente:

[image: Diccionario de parametros]

Cual seria la forma correcta de hacer esta solicitud incluyendo el archivo?

P.D.: el archivo lo tengo como base64 o lo puedo convertir en byte[]

Comment: Por favor, el código como texto y no como imagen. Te invito a repasar [ask]. Adicionalmente, tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones, ¿tienes un problema en concreto o simplemente quieres saber qué camino seguir? Recuerda que las preguntas basadas en opiniones suelen terminar cerradas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu comentario. Lo voy a tener en cuenta. El problema que tengo, resumiendo, es que no se como replicar la solicitud de Postman en C#.

Comment: en tu urlEncoded, debrias agregar el parametro, yo siempre lo paso como un Byte[],  y normalmente lo hago con json para enviar y recibir todo como un objeto y manejarlo siempre de la misma forma.

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias por tu comentario. Tendrias un ejemplo para verlo mas claro? O sea, agrego el parametro de esta forma (dentro del diccionario, agrego un nuevo item): { "files[0]", contenidoArchivo.ToString() } siendo contenidoArchivo un byte[]